# Does using a rate limiter within parallel goroutines cause race conditions?

Tags: go, asynchronous, goroutine

As a heavy simplification of my code, I have a goroutine that gets ran thousands of times in parallel, with each one waiting to run via a rate limiter from `golang.org/x/time/rate`:

```golang
func main() {
  limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(time.Second/100), 1) // 100 RPS

  for _ := range jobs {
    go run(&limiter)
  }
}

func run(limiter *rate.Limiter) {
  limiter.Wait()

  // do stuff...
}
```

The idea is to have `run()` execute as often as possible, but limited to exactly 100 calls / sec in order to comply with a third-party API's rate limit of 100 RPS.

Would this cause a race condition when `limiter.Wait()` allows the execution to proceed? Because I'm still being rate limited by the third party.

Comment: There is no race condition in the code you show.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Even though it's accessing `limiter` from separate threads at the potentially the exact same time?

Comment: That is how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: Unless otherwise stated in the docs, packages from `golang.org` will most certainly be goroutine-safe. Looking [at the source](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/time/+/e5dcc9cf:rate/rate.go;l=217,) it's evident that channels & locks are used which ensures synchronized access to shared resources

Comment: Got it, thanks for the confirmation @colm.anseo !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

`limiter.Wait()` is concurrent safe, you can see this in source files of Limiter's implementation.

You are free to use Limiter in any concurrent scenario.